# How to store images and names in android

Tags: android

I have a GirdView with an image and a categoryname. I am getting the name and image from server. I am using Universal Image Loader for loading the images. I want that when the user opens the application it should load the images and category_name once and save it so that the user can directly see the images and category_name without loading. This is my MainActivity

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    al_city = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    al_category = new ArrayList<Pojo>();

    //Grid View
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    new NetCheck().execute();
}



private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        nDialog.dismiss();
        adapter = new CategoriesAdapter(MainActivity.this, al_category);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
          HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          String url = Config.CITIESCATEGORIES;
              HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(url);
              httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

              JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

              Log.e("JSON Object", json.toString());

              StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
              se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
              se.setContentType("application/json");
              httpRequest.setEntity(se);
              HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
              java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpRes.getEntity()
                    .getContent();
              InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              inputStream.close();
              strServerResponse = sb.toString();
              Log.e("Server Response", "" + strServerResponse.toString());
              if (strServerResponse != null) {

              JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
              for (int i = 0; i<arr.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    objCity = jobj2.getString("city");
                    objCategory = jobj2.getString("category");
                    imagePath = jobj2.getString("cat_img_path");

                }

                JSONArray gg = new JSONArray(objCity);
                for (int j=0; j<gg.length(); j++){
                    pojo = new Pojo();
                    JSONObject jobj = gg.getJSONObject(j);
                    String cityid = jobj.optString("id");
                    String cityName = jobj.optString("name");
                    pojo.setCityId(cityid);
                    pojo.setCityName(cityName);
                    al_city.add(pojo);
                }

                JSONArray ff = new JSONArray(objCategory);
                for (int j=0; j<ff.length(); j++){
                    pojo = new Pojo();
                    JSONObject jobj3 = ff.getJSONObject(j);
                    String catId = jobj3.optString("id");
                    String imagename = jobj3.optString("image");
                    String catname = jobj3.optString("name");

                    pojo.setCategoryId(catId);
                    pojo.setCatImage(imagename);
                    pojo.setCatName(catname);
                    al_category.add(pojo);
                }

            } else {
               Log.e("ServiceHandler",
                        "Couldn't get any data from the url");
           } 
   }
```

And this CategoriesAdapter

```
  public class CategoriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
TextView categoryName;
ImageView catImage;
Pojo pojo;
private Context activity1;
ArrayList<Pojo> data1;
private ArrayList<Pojo> arraylist1 = null;
public static LayoutInflater inflater;

public CategoriesAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Pojo> catt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    activity1 = ctx;
    data1 = catt;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity1
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.arraylist1 = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    this.arraylist1.addAll(data1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data1.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data1.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;

    pojo = new Pojo();
   // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            activity1)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    pojo = data1.get(position);
    categoryName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    catImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    categoryName.setText(pojo.getCatName());
    String url = Config.BASEURL+""+ MainActivity.imagePath+"/"+""+pojo.getCatImage();
    Log.e("imageurl",""+url);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.picc)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.picc)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.picc).build();


    imageLoader.displayImage(url, catImage, options);

    return v;
 }
```

Please help me. How to do this.

Comment: Save the image some where in the device, and after saving get the path and store it inside database for particular ID.

Comment: You can store image in catch first time and get image from catch after first time.

Comment: Priyanka did u get invitation ? You can chat there

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences for storing key-value string values or you can store the values in an SQLite database. You can check more options [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

I always use **SharedPreferences.**
For example:
I want to store an Image.
Yu add int j; (sharedpreferences) and if your value j is equals 1 then use your SharedPreferences's int and store it.
The same with sharedPreferences strings.
You have got an [explanation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)